# How can this expression reach the NULL expression?

Tags: sql-server, null

I'm trying to randomly populate a column with values from another table using this statement:

```
UPDATE dbo.SERVICE_TICKET    
SET Vehicle_Type = (SELECT TOP 1 [text]
                    FROM dbo.vehicle_typ 
                    WHERE id = abs(checksum(NewID()))%21)
```

It seems to work fine, however the value `NULL` is inserted into the column. How can I get rid of the `NULL` and only insert the values from the table?

Comment: Thats not a `mysql` syntax, update the question and change the tag.

Comment: That is not `mysql`syntax. please use the `sql-server` tags.

Comment: Are there rows in `vehicle_typ` with all possible IDs from `0` to `20`? If not, that's where the `NULL`s are arising from.

Comment: Yes, the vehicle_typ includes all possible rows from 0 to 20 - so this cannot be the reson for the NULL.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen when you don't have an appropriate index on the `ID` column of your `vehicle_typ` table. Here's a smaller query that exhibits the same problem:

```
create table T (ID int null)
insert into T(ID) values (0),(1),(2),(3)
select top 1 * from T where ID = abs(checksum(NewID()))%3
```

Because there's no index on `T`, what happens is that SQL Server performs a table scan and then, for each row, attempts to satisfy the where clause. Which means that, for *each* row it evaluates `abs(checksum(NewID()))%3` anew. You'll only get a result if, by chance, that expression produces, say, `1` *when* it's evaluated for the row with `ID` 1.

If possible (I don't know your table structure) I would *first* populate a column in `SERVICE_TICKET` with a random number between 0 and 20 and *then* perform this update using the already generated number. Otherwise, with the current query structure, you're always relying on SQL Server being clever enough to only evaluate `abs(checksum(NewID()))%21`once for each outer row, which it may not always do (as you've already found out).

Comment: Ok, I see the problem ... so how can I change my expression from above to get rid of this problem?

Comment: @LKH - I don't know which version of my answer you read - I added a new paragraph at the bottom with one suggestion of how I'd try to address the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I created a clustered Index and the NULL disappeared. However, now every value is the same ... do you know how to get randomly different values being not NULL?

Answer (score 1):

@Damien_The_Unbeliever explained why your query fails.

My first variant was not correct, because I didn't understand the problem in full.

You want to set each row in `SERVICE_TICKET` to a different random value from `vehicle_typ`.

To fix it simply order by random number, rather than comparing a random number with `ID`. Like this (and you don't care how many rows are in `vehicle_typ` as long as there is at least one row there).

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        dbo.SERVICE_TICKET.Vehicle_Type
        CA.[text]
    FROM
        dbo.SERVICE_TICKET
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 [text]
            FROM dbo.vehicle_typ
            ORDER BY NewID()
        ) AS CA
)
UPDATE CTE
SET Vehicle_Type = [text];
```

At first we make a Common Table Expression, you can think of it as a temporary table. For each row in `SERVICE_TICKET` we pick one random row from `vehicle_typ` using `CROSS APPLY`. Then we `UPDATE` the original table with chosen rows.

Comment: I copied the expression exactly as you described. However, I can not execute it because the multi-part identifier dbo.SERVICE_TICKET.Vehicle_Type
could not be found.
Besides CROSS APPLY is greyed out.

Comment: @LKH, I don't understand why you are getting the error. If you try simple `SELECT dbo.SERVICE_TICKET.Vehicle_Type FROM dbo.SERVICE_TICKET` does it work?